# Python how to "import #variable#"

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a beginner in Python these problems confuses me. Coming from PHP it's very easy to use variables like this.

In PHP you would do

```
$myvar = 'test.php';
require(""+$myvar+"");
```

I want to do something similar in Python. I am developing a simple GUI that is basically a dropdown which lists all .py files in the directory, then I want to execute them kind of like this:

```
imp = input("import? ")
import imp
imp.run()
```

test.py contains:

```
def run():
    print("hey")
```

So basically the goal is to be able to type "test" in console (and later select "test" in dropdown list) and have the run() function in test.py execute.

Comment: `importlib.import_module(modname)`. It also takes an optional `package=` argument.